# Hough transform returns the collinear and semi collinear points

Tags: c++, opencv, hough-transform

I have points in an image. I need to detect the most collinear points. The fastest method is to use Hough transform, but I have to modify the opencv method. Actually I need that the semi collinear points to be returned with detected line, for this reason I modified the polar line struct. A tolerance threshold is also needed to detect nearly detected points as shown in the image. Can someone help in how to tune this threshold?
I need at least four semi collinear points to detect the line to which they belong. 
[image: ex 1]
[image: ex 2]
[image: ex 3]

1. The points of first image were detected by 6 overlapped lines
2. the point of middle images were detected by nothing
3. the third's points
   were detected by three lines

[image: `![enter image description here]
[image]
[image]

Which is the best way to get rid from the overlapped liens?? Or how to tune the tolerance threshold to detect the semi collinear points by only one line?

the is my own function call:

```
vector<CvLinePolar2> lines;
CvMat c_image = source1; // loaded image
HoughLinesStandard(&c_image,1,CV_PI/180,4,&lines,INT_MAX);
```

---

```
    typedef struct CvLinePolar2
    {
      float rho;
      float angle;
      vector<CvPoint> points;
    };

void HoughLinesStandard( const CvMat* img, float rho, float theta,
                   int threshold, vector<CvLinePolar2> *lines, int linesMax= INT_MAX )
{
cv::AutoBuffer<int> _accum, _sort_buf;
cv::AutoBuffer<float> _tabSin, _tabCos;


const uchar* image;
int step, width, height;
int numangle, numrho;
int total = 0;
int i, j;
float irho = 1 / rho;
double scale;

vector<vector<CvPoint>> lpoints;
CV_Assert( CV_IS_MAT(img) && CV_MAT_TYPE(img->type) == CV_8UC1 );

image = img->data.ptr;
step = img->step;
width = img->cols;
height = img->rows;

numangle = cvRound(CV_PI / theta);
numrho = cvRound(((width + height) * 2 + 1) / rho);

_accum.allocate((numangle+2) * (numrho+2));
_sort_buf.allocate(numangle * numrho);
_tabSin.allocate(numangle);
_tabCos.allocate(numangle);
int *accum = _accum, *sort_buf = _sort_buf;
float *tabSin = _tabSin, *tabCos = _tabCos;

memset( accum, 0, sizeof(accum[0]) * (numangle+2) * (numrho+2) );
//memset( lpoints, 0, sizeof(lpoints) );
lpoints.resize(sizeof(accum[0]) * (numangle+2) * (numrho+2));
float ang = 0;
for(int n = 0; n < numangle; ang += theta, n++ )
{
    tabSin[n] = (float)(sin(ang) * irho);
    tabCos[n] = (float)(cos(ang) * irho);
}

// stage 1. fill accumulator
for( i = 0; i < height; i++ )
    for( j = 0; j < width; j++ )
    {
        if( image[i * step + j] != 0 )
        {
            CvPoint pt;
            pt.x = j; pt.y = i;
            for(int n = 0; n < numangle; n++ )
            {
                int r = cvRound( j * tabCos[n] + i * tabSin[n] );
                r += (numrho - 1) / 2;

                int ind = (n+1) * (numrho+2) + r+1;
                int s = accum[ind];
                accum[ind]++;

                lpoints[ind].push_back(pt);


            }

        }
    }

// stage 2. find local maximums
for(int r = 0; r < numrho; r++ )
    for(int n = 0; n < numangle; n++ )
    {
        int base = (n+1) * (numrho+2) + r+1;
        if( accum[base] > threshold &&
            accum[base] > accum[base - 1] && accum[base] >= accum[base + 1] &&
            accum[base] > accum[base - numrho - 2] && accum[base] >= accum[base + numrho + 2] )
            sort_buf[total++] = base;
    }

// stage 3. sort the detected lines by accumulator value
icvHoughSortDescent32s( sort_buf, total, accum );

// stage 4. store the first min(total,linesMax) lines to the output buffer
linesMax = MIN(linesMax, total);
scale = 1./(numrho+2);
for( i = 0; i < linesMax; i++ )
{
    CvLinePolar2 line;
    int idx = sort_buf[i];
    int n = cvFloor(idx*scale) - 1;
    int r = idx - (n+1)*(numrho+2) - 1;
    line.rho = (r - (numrho - 1)*0.5f) * rho;
    line.angle = n * theta;

    line.points = lpoints[idx];

    lines->push_back(line);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

One approach is [non-maximal suppression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector#Non-maximum_suppression) to thin out the candidate set for potential lines. Once you've identified the thinned potential lines you could then compute an average of the remaining lines that would satisfy some angular or spatial difference threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Try `HoughLinesP`..[opencv reference](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=hough#houghlinesp)

Comment: I know it is more suitable for my case, but it does not return the collinear points